# Javascript: Compare objects in array with eachother once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
myList = [{key: A, val: 12},{key:B, val: 2},{key: A, val: 4}]
```

I want to compare the objects in my array with each other and check for any conflicts where the same key is found. I can simple foreach and compare it to the whole list but what I want to do is only compare each object once and skip the ones it hasn't been compared to all ready.

So the first iteration {key: A, val: 12} will be compared to {key:B, val: 2} and {key: A, val: 4}

The second iteration {key:B, val: 2} will only be compared to {key: A, val: 4} since it was all ready compared to {key: A, val: 12} in the first iteration.

The last iteration {key: A, val: 4} wont be compared to anything since it was compared all ready in the previous iterations.

I am not entirely sure on how to write a loop like this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops and start the inner loop at the next index after the current index of the outer loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length-1; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < myList.length; j++) {
    // compare myList[i] with myList[j]
  }
}
```